# html2canvas not rendering/capturing the svg's completely on firefox

Tags: firefox, svg, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas to save a webpage as png. Html2canvas is rendering/capturing svg's correctly in Opera and Chrome. However it is not rendering/capturing svg's completely on firefox. This is the code I am using. I am also using the latest html2canvas.

```
  $(function() {
                 $("#btnSave").click(function() {
                        html2canvas($("#widget"), {
                            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                                /* theCanvas = canvas;
                                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                               // Convert and download as image
                                Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
                                $("#img-out").append(canvas);
                                 window.open(canvas);
                                 */

                                  var a = document.createElement('a');
                                 // toDataURL defaults to png, so we need to request a jpeg, then convert for file download.
                                 document.body.appendChild(a);
                                 a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
                                 a.download = 'Human Insights - O&E.png';
                                 a.click();
                                // Clean up
                                //document.body.removeChild(canvas);

                                 // toDataURL defaults to png, so we need to request a jpeg, then convert for file download.
                            }
                        }, {
                            allowTaint: true,
                        });
                    });
                });
```

[This is the image captured using html2canvas on firefox version :56.0 running on windows 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fvjnd.png)

[This is the image captured using html2canvas on chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) running on windows 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0BfZ.png)

Comment: Please check the image that I have uploaded.

Comment: We're still going to need a [mcve]

Comment: I have included 0.5.0-beta4/html2canvas.js in the head section. I have added a button (#btnSave) on clicking that button the webpage is converted and downloaded as png. The above mentioned script is placed in the footer.

Comment: So I can use any svg to recreate this issue?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I am using linearguage.js. This is creating a svg linear guage. Please refer the screenshots for the linear guage.  ... Sorry newbie here...